# How to use bufferedImage output color histogram

Tags: java, jframe, visualization, histogram, bufferedimage

I now have a jpeg pic, and already have list of RGB channels value. I would like to use bufferedImage to produce a new color histogram of the picture. the format of the output could be jpeg or any format.

Jframe seems not available to be turned to buffered image.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a BufferedImage make your program an Applet